# How to call abstract class methods to another class in java

Tags: java, abstract-class

can anybody tell me that. how can I call abstract class method to my own class in java?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can clarify a bit your question. Do you want your abstract class to call its abstract method from another, non-abstract method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to first create a subclass of the abstract class. This will then contain the methods of that abstract class. You use the "extends" keyword.

For example:

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractClass 
{
   //class content here...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

First of all look at you abstract class, it shall contain abstract methods and real methods. In the following sample the Foo class has an abstract method (FooMethod) and a real method (Yeee).

```
public abstract class Foo {

  public abstract int FooMethod(int i);

  public int Yeeee() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       int res = FooMethod(i);
       // Do whatever
    }
  }
}
```

Abstract class are not meant to be directly used, so we have to inherit from them with a concrete class. The following inherits from the abstract (implementing the abstract method)

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
  public int FooMethod(int i) {
    // do something with i
  }

  public static void main (string [] args) {
      Bar obj = new Bar();
      obj.Yeeee();
  }
}
```

Note: when in the main you call obj.Yeee() the base class method gets invoked, but in place of the abstract FooMethod, your own new implementation is used.

This is just the tip of the iceberg with abstract classes, but roughly should point you to the right direction.

Please take a good read [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=288) is a good tutorial and should give you some initial wisdom about inheritance and abstract classes.

Comment: i was searching for this . abstract class method implementation of child class can be called within abstract class. is it ???

Comment: indirectly, within an abstract class method you can call the abstract method. When you'll have a real instance (so a derived concrete class), the derived class' method will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

For methods in abstract classes you need not to create the instance of the abstract class
So after importing the package in which the abstract class is present you can just call the method as below

YourAbstractClassName.methodName(args if any);

Answer (score 1):

since abstract classes cant be instanciated in Java, You cant have member functions in this class and if you want to have one than their is a logical problem. However if you want to call the static methods, you can simply call them using class name, i.e.

```
YourClassName.fuctionName(parameters if any);
```

Comment: thx for ur quick reply. I wan to call simply a method which is not a static method. then how to call this method

Comment: Abstract classes are classes which can't be instantiated, However you can extend these classes and methods (if public or protected this is ridiculous to have private methods in an abstract class) can be called using the objects of derived class. Which shouldn't be an abstract class by nature....

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to implement that method in your class ? 
if that is what you want to understand 
then you just have to extend your class with the abstract one

for example

abstract class GraphicObject {....}

class Circle extends GraphicObject { ... }

try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method in abstract class  by creating an
object of subclasss of the abstract class
or
if u want to call from the abstract class then you have to make your method static then you can call from main method like
Abstract_className.methodName()

Comment: Hi @Subhasis. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for contributing to this great community, but when answering questions, please make sure you provide novel information or information with better clarity. In short, make sure its something unique :)